# Custom Post type: Labels are not showing in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I created `custom-post-type.php` file in folder of `mu-plugins`:

```
<?php 
    
    function custom_post_types(){
        register_post_type('event', array(
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Events',
                'edit_item'=>'Edit Event',
                'edit_posts' => 'Add New Event',
                'all_items' => 'All Events'
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar'
        ));
      }
      
add_action('init', 'custom_post_types');
```

These two labels name of `'edit_item'=> 'Edit Event', & 'edit_posts' => 'Add New Event'` not working. I wanted to know where i am mistaken. Can somebody help? Thank you!

Comment: There is no `edit_posts` key for labels, but there is a capability of that name. Based on that value, I think you want `add_new`.

Comment: `'add_new'=> 'Edit Event', &  'edit_item' => 'Add New Event'` still not working

Comment: Do you have any other plugins installed that might be trumping this? What is showing instead of "Edit Event" and "Add New Event"?

Comment: @ChrisHaas https://i.postimg.cc/cCfsSZkn/image.png
No other plugin is installed except classic editor. It is showing default name as `edit post`. Check the image

Comment: @ChrisHaas still cannot figure it out? Can we continue to chat?

Comment: Sorry, the only thing that I can tell you is that when I try your code above, with an `add_new` key of `Add New Event`, it is working for me. Permalinks shouldn't have anything to do with this. Is there a chance that you started this in functions.php before moving it to an mu-plugin, and you have a remnant there?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes i started in `functions.php` and moved the code in mu-plugins by changing the name of the `university-post-types` to `custom_post_types`. if this is creating problem then what is the solution for now on?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much @ChrisHaas it is working now.